# Face of brick fell off. Can I glue/cement it back on? How?

Tags: repair, brick

The face of one brick fell off while I was removing spalled concrete below it.
Can I glue/cement the face back on? How? The face is fairly thick (1/4 " maybe).
The yellow hammer is holding it so you can see where it fell off.
[image: face of brick fell off]

Comment: Why not?   Can't hurt to try.  There's some amazing glues out there these days.  Gorrilla Glue comes to mind as something that might actually hold up.   Or a thorough coating of RTV.  Just make sure you get all the cracks sealed so water can't get behind it (and freeze, thus pushing the face off over time)   Clean the surface first with some alcohol and water and let dry before applying glue.   Make sure there's no dust residue.  I know what likely WON'T hold it is standard mortar mix.  You need something that works under tension (being pulled).... That stuff is best under compression.

Comment: Lowes recommended Constructive Adhesive (comes in caulking tube).  I bought it but won't be doing the work for a couple days, so I will check for additional comments before I complete the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the face of the brick isn't structural and doesn't need to hold any weight, gluing it back on will be fine.  One thing I would worry about is water intrusion into the repair that might cause the thin face to crumble.

Construction adhesive would be fine, and they even have some formulated for landscaping bricks that should work great for this.  I would get a disposable, stiff bristle brush and evenly, lightly cover both faces of the repair.  Then push the face into place, and lean something heavy against it to hold it in place.

The even coat of adhesive should keep water out and allow the repair to last a long time.